# BigQuery google.cloud.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable 503

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-python-api

From time to time we getting error from google while working with BigQuery API

> File "../.venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/dataset.py", line 452, in exists
>           query_params={'fields': 'id'})
>
> File "../.venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
>           raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
>       google.cloud.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects//datasets/?fields=id: Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem.

Caused by python code

```
   destination_dataset.exists()
```

Our system:

- Python 3.4
- google-cloud-bigquery==0.26.0
- google-cloud==0.27.0

Last time this error has occurred:

- 6.02.18 at 10:31pm CET
- 4.02.18 at 6:30am CET
- 25.01.19 at 8:50pm CET
- 25.01.19 at 10:34pm CET

Any ideas why it happening and how we can avoid this error?

Comment: You cannot avoid errors like these. BigQuery's SLA (and most other public cloud provider services) is something like 99.99%. It's not 100%. You need to account for these types of errors/problems in your code by using strategies like exponential back-off-and-retry e.g. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff (GCS)

Answer (score 0):

Adding here documentation links, to the excellent comment by Graham Polley. You may read "[Truncated Exponential Backoff](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff)" and the "[Exponential Backoff](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#exp-backoff)" sub-chapter of the "Loading Data into BigQuery from a Local Data Source" documentation page.